# why can't implicitly convert to a std::variant with std::atomic_bool

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm writing a factory to for my classes, but having trouble compiling

```cpp
struct A {
    std::atomic_bool flag{}; // remove this, there would be no error
    A() = default;
};

struct B {};

using base = std::variant<A, B>;

base create() {
    return A();
}
```

I got the error:

```sh
error: could not convert 'A()' from 'A' to 'base{aka std::variant<A, B>}'
return A();
```

why is this happenning? and why would it work if I remove `std::atomic_bool` in `A`?

Comment: Atomics are not copyable

Comment: `std::atomic` is not copyable so you can't copy `A` either

Answer (score 1):

Atomics do not support being copied.  If you want to copy them, you are in charge of deciding what the memory orders and the like of the read and write is.

Atomics are fundamentally identity based, not value based.  They exist because you expect certain kinds of comtention on their identity.

```
constexpr atomic() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>);
constexpr atomic( T desired ) noexcept;
atomic( const atomic& ) = delete;
```

Generally a struct being copied around with an atomic in it is code smell.  You may have a design flaw.

If not, you need to define what the copy means yourself.  I am unaware of an obviously correct choice.

Comment: thx. actually, I would prefer `A` to be non-copyable, but does it mean that there is no way I can get it via a factory? I tried adding move constructor and move assignment, but it seems not helping

Comment: Just `return {};`?

Comment: `return base(std::in_place_type<A>()));`